# How to treat each element as single over array in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have an array of products, I want to change the element src only on the one I'm hovering on. If there is a way of doing it in Vuejs I would like to know. My code so far

```
  <div class="swiper-slide" v-for="(prodotto,index) in prodotti" :key="prodotto.title">
   <img @mouseover="swapImage(index)" @mouseleave="swapImageLeave" class="swiper-lazy ima-prodotto" :key="index" :src=" hoverProdotti === 1 ? prodotto.images[0] : prodotto.images[1]" v- 
            bind:alt="prodotto.title">
       </div>
```

```
const app = new Vue({

    el: "#root",
  
    data: {

      hoverProdotti:0,
  
    },
  
    methods: {
  
      swapImage: function(index) {
       console.log(index)
        this.hoverProdotti = 1
      },
      swapImageLeave: function() {
    
        this.hoverProdotti = 0
      },
```

Comment: `hoverProdotti[]`, i.e declared as an array, update it using `this.hoverProdotti[index]` and use it like `:src = "hoverProdotti[index] === 1 .... etc"`

Comment: Your design is flawed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `prodotto.images` is an array with couple of images in it and your requirement is to show the image on the **0th index** when hovered and show the image on the **1st index** when un-hovered.

```
<div class="swiper-slide" v-for="(prodotto,index) in prodotti" :key="prodotto.title">
  <img 
    @mouseover="hoverProdotti = index" 
    @mouseleave="hoverProdotti = null" 
    class="swiper-lazy ima-prodotto" 
    :key="index" 
    :src="hoverProdotti === index ? prodotto.images[0] : prodotto.images[1]" 
    :alt="prodotto.title"
  />
</div>

data: {
  hoverProdotti:null,
},
```

---

**Code explanation**:

Assign 'null' value to `hoverProdotti` variable.
Inside the `v-for` when you mouse over on a specific element, it's index gets assigned to `hoverProdotti`, which would fulfill the condition we have placed in `:src`. And as soon as mouse leaves, `hoverProdotti` gets `null` value assigned.

With this logic, it will swap images on your mouseover and mouseleave for the all the elements of the array.

Note: No need of `methods` or any `functions`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply achieve this by adding a `hoverProdotti` property in each object of `prodotti` array with default value as `false`. The reason behind this is that it should be dynamic to implement the swap logic only for the specific `hover` image not for all images.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    prodotti: [{
      title: 'Title 1',
      images: [
        'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=Swapped Image',
        'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=Non Swapped Image'
      ],
      hoverProdotti: false
    }, {
      title: 'Title 2',
      images: [
        'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=Swapped Image',
        'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=Non Swapped Image'
      ],
      hoverProdotti: false
    }, {
      title: 'Title 3',
      images: [
        'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=Swapped Image',
        'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=Non Swapped Image'
      ],
      hoverProdotti: false
    }, {
      title: 'Title 4',
      images: [
        'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=Swapped Image',
        'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=Non Swapped Image'
      ],
      hoverProdotti: false
    }],
  },
  methods: {
    swapImage(index) {
      this.prodotti[index].hoverProdotti = true
    },
    swapImageLeave(index) {
      this.prodotti[index].hoverProdotti = false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(prodotto,index) in prodotti" :key="prodotto.title">
    <img @mouseover="swapImage(index)" @mouseleave="swapImageLeave(index)" :key="index" :src="prodotto.hoverProdotti ? prodotto.images[0] : prodotto.images[1]" :alt="prodotto.title">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's another good solution thank you! I have to map through the array first and give it a arrayItem.hoverProdotti = false but it's not what we really want to do now

Comment: In that case you can go with the solution which @Shreeraj provided.